# Reset HTML element to default value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, default-value

**Problem:**

I am wondering if there is a similar function that allows resetting a text to its default value like there is for the value attribute.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="range" class="custom-range" name="studyslider" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="50" oninput="sliderChange(this)" onchange="sliderChange(this)">
<output class="badge badge-light badge-width mt-4 mb-3" name="studyslider-output">50</output>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Resetting the value for <input>
const slider = node.querySelector(".custom-range");
slider.value = slider.defaultValue;

// Resetting the value for <output>
const sliderOutput = node.querySelector("output");
sliderOutput.innerHTML = "50";
```

**Desired output:**

To pick up the value inside `<output>` and resetting it every time an answer is submitted, similar to that of `defaultValue` for `<input>`.

Comment: Could you not use `silderOutput.value`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox There is no value attribute for `<output>` and what I am asking was if there was a way to avoid hard-coding "50" in JS, but instead pick it up from the HTML instead in a dynamic way.

Comment: I guess you'll have to pick it up from the HTML before overwriting it the first time.

Comment: What about using a `data` attribute? (Output does have a `value` attribute https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-output-element)

Comment: Of course the ideal solution would be to have `slider.value = slider.defaultValue; sliderChange(slider);` lead to the original "default" output value as well.

Comment: imo cleanest way will be using the native reset button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to assign the value of `slider.defaultValue` to `sliderOutput.innerHTML`, Why not just do this ?

`// Resetting the value for <input>
const slider = node.querySelector(".custom-range");
slider.value = slider.defaultValue;`

`// Resetting the value for <output>
const sliderOutput = node.querySelector("output");
sliderOutput.innerHTML = slider.defaultValue;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use data-X attribute:

```
<output data-default-value="50">50</output>
```

JS:

```
sliderOutput.innerHTML = sliderOutput.dataset.defaultValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the native reset.

```js
function sliderChange(e) {
  document.getElementById("output").value = document.getElementById("slider").value
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="slider" type="range" class="custom-range" name="studyslider" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="50" oninput="sliderChange(this)" onchange="sliderChange(this)">
  <output class="badge badge-light badge-width mt-4 mb-3" name="studyslider-output" id="output">50</output>
<input type="reset" />
</form>
```